# Number of subsets of $U$ whose arithmetic mean is integral

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, conjectures

Question is :-

> $n$ is a positive integer. Call a non-empty subset $S$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ "good" if the arithmetic mean of
>   elements of $S$ is also an integer. Further Let $t_n$ denote the number of
>   good subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$. Prove that $t_n$ and $n$ are both odd
>   or both even.

And my solution to this problem is :-

> We deal with problem in 2 cases : n is even and other when n is odd.
>   If n is odd , we first calculate n={1,2} by brute force. We get numbers
>   of solutions for n=1 as 1 & n=3 as 5. Thus we conjecture that
>   $t_n$=$t_{n-2}+2(n-1)$ for n as even. So by this recurrence we
>   calculate $t_5$ which comes to be 15. A brute force manual calculation
>   confirms this answer . Thus we prove our conjecture by induction. Now
>   $t_1$ is odd (=1) so $t_2$ has to be odd since $t_2$=$t_1+2(3-1)$,here
>   $t_1$ is odd & other term is even thus overall parity is odd. So $t_2$
>   is odd. Again $t_3$ has to be odd as $t_3$=$t_2$+2(3-1), $t_2$ is odd
>   & other term even , so $t_3$ is odd. So , inductively we conclude that
>   $t_n$ has to be odd . For the other case we conjecture same recurrence
>   relation and prove in the same way.

Comment: "subset $S$ of $S$"? And what is AM?

Comment: What does this mean? *"if AM of elements of S is also an integer"* Also, it is inadvisable to use idiosyncratic abbreviations for short words like "numbers".

Comment: @rschwieb: If the arithmetic mean of the elements of $S$ is also an integer.

Comment: Maggi, you’ve messed up some of your subscripts in the solution. You should have $t_3=t_1+2(3-1)$, not $t_2=t_1+2(2-1)$.

Comment: I went ahead and edited in "arithmetic mean" since more than one reader seems to recognize that's what it should be. I think someone needs to think of a better title, though...

Comment: @rschwieb: It’s a very common abbreviation in contest circles, as is ‘AM-GM inequality’.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for the rather unrelated trivia, but as you can see I accepted the suggestion at face value the first time you mentioned it, and it's not as if I expressed doubt. Perhaps you could point these comments at Hagen von Eitzen from now on... he asked about the abbreviation too.

Comment: @rschwieb: I thought that you might have been at least a little curious about why some folks recognized it. And since in my language ‘*seems* to recognize’ [emphasis added] suggests at least a trace amount of doubt, I was offering further reassurance that the edit was reasonable, should any be necessary. The comment was directed at you because you were the one who made the edit.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Fortunately "seems" means the same thing in my language, but it is an unfortunate miscommunication that that was somehow associated with doubting you. It was intended to express strong belief as in "Because I see Brian and another person recognize it, I believe it's the right interpretation."

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Yeah proffessor you pointed out my genuine mistake :)

Comment: https://oeis.org/A051293

Comment: Thanks Charles , it was useful :D Vote up ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. For $S\subseteq[n]$ let $\mu(S)$ be the arithmetic mean of $S$. For $m\in[n]$ let $$\mathscr{S}_m=\big\{S\subseteq[n]:\mu(S)=m\text{ and }S\ne\{m\}\big\}\;.$$ If $m\notin S\in\mathscr{S}_m$, then $S\cup\{m\}\in\mathscr{S}_m$. If $m\in S\in\mathscr{S}_m$, then $S\setminus\{m\}\in\mathscr{S}_m$. Let $$\mathscr{S}_m^*=\{S\in\mathscr{S}_m:m\in S\}\;.$$ Then the map

$$\mathscr{S}_m^*\to\mathscr{S}_m\setminus\mathscr{S}_m^*:S\mapsto S\setminus\{m\}$$

is a bijection, and $|\mathscr{S}_m|$ is even. The good subsets of $[n]$ that do not belong to $\bigcup_{m\in[n]}\mathscr{S}_m$ are precisely the singletons $\{1\},\dots,\{n\}$. If $\mathscr{S}$ is the set of all good subsets, we have

$$|\mathscr{S}|=\left|\bigcup_{m\in[n]}\mathscr{S}_m\right|+n\equiv n\pmod2\;.$$

(This was problem A3 on the 2002 Putnam.)

**Added in response to comment:** Here’s an example of what’s going on in this proof. Take $n=7$. Then the members of $\mathscr{S}_3$, the subsets of $[7]$ whose average is $3$ (other than the singleton $\{3\}$), are

$$\begin{align*}
&\{1,5\},\{2,4\},\\
&\{1,2,6\},\{1,3,5\},\{2,3,4\},\\
&\{1,2,3,6\},\{1,2,4,5\},\text{ and}\\
&\{1,2,3,4,5\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

They can be paired up:

$$\begin{align*}
\{1,5\}&\leftrightarrow\{1,\underline{3},5\}\\
\{2,4\}&\leftrightarrow\{2,\underline{3},4\}\\
\{1,2,6\}&\leftrightarrow\{1,2,\underline{3},6\}\\
\{1,2,4,5\}&\leftrightarrow\{1,2,\underline{3},4,5\}
\end{align*}$$

The argument shows that this happens with each collection of subsets all having the same average; that accounts for an even number of good subsets altogether. The only good subsets left are $\{1\},\{2\},\dots,\{7\}$, the same as the original $n$. Thus, we always have $n$ good singletons together with an even number of other good subsets of $[n]$.

Comment: Thanks proffessor (but i couldnt understand solution completly :P), and it was problem P4 in INMO held today today xD They just copied putnam contest problem and many had solved this question before , so unfair!

Comment: @Maggi: I added a bit to make the idea of the argument clearer.

Comment: Okay proffessor ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Let  $A$ be the set of good  subsets of $U=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Then 
$$f\colon S=\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}\mapsto n+1-S=\{n+1-a_k,\ldots,n+1-a_1\}$$
is a bijection $A\to A$ because the average $\overline{f(S)}$ of $f(S)$ is $n+1$ minus the average $\overline S$ of $S$, i.e. if one is integral so is the other. 
Since $f$ is an involution, $A$ can be partitioned into pairs $\{S, f(S)\}$ and the set $A^f$ of fixpoints of $f$. Thus $|A|\equiv |A^f|\pmod 2$.
Buf if $S=f(S)$ is a fixpoint of $f$, then $\overline S=\frac{n+1}2$ because $\overline S=\overline{f(S)}=n+1-\overline S$.
This is integral if and only if $n$ is odd. Hence for $n$ even we have immediately $|A|\equiv|A^f|\equiv 0\pmod 2$.
On the other hand, if $n=2m-1$ is odd, then 
$$g\colon S\mapsto S\Delta\{m\}$$ (symmetric difference) is *almost* an involutory bijection $A^f\to A^f$: The exception is the one-element set $\{m\}$ that gets mapped to the empty set. In other words, $g$ defines an involution of $A^f\cup\emptyset$. Since $g$ clearly has no fixpoints, we see that $A^f\cup \emptyset$ has an even number of elements, i.e. $|A|\equiv|A^f|\equiv 1\pmod 2$.

Comment: Well it appears to be correct (votes up) but i couldnt understand most of it , it may be useful for other people viewing thread but can you tell me wether my solution is correct , i will be grateful :)

Comment: I simplified the argumentation by introducing another involution, hope that helps. Your original solution cannot be correct as the recursion is definitely wrong: From the symmetric sets (i.e. $A^f$) alone, necessarily $t_{2m+1}\ge 2^m$ and $t_{2m}\ge 2^m$.

Comment: Yeah Hagen , i think you are correct , i made a program to know that i was wrong , thanks for help :)